# xterm do not refresh page after ssh

Tags: vim, ssh, xterm

when I sshed into another machine in xterm, the character I deleted by either backspacce or ctrl+k, remains on the screen. but physically they have been deleted, as when you exectue the script, the machine responds in a way that the delete has conducted. The only way to display properly is to let the cursor moving through the deleted words, either by space or typing other characters.

Same thing applies when you using vim. specifically after page down, the screen displays a overlap between the previous page and current page.

The screen displays properly without ssh.

I am using gentoo with the following compile flag (if it is related).

[ebuild   R    ] x11-terms/xterm-314  USE="openpty truetype unicode -Xaw3d -toolbar" 0 KiB

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a locale problem.  Some Linux's by the way honor an stty `-iutf8` setting, and others may not.  Either that, or a difference in locale settings on the local and remote machines is the first place to check.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas's answer led me to a solution for this very same problem. My LANG environment variable was incorrectly set on my local machine. For my case,setting `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` 
fixed the problem.